# ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [result defaultRepresentation]; GETS ERROR

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am trying to do

```
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [result defaultRepresentation];
```

but gets following error-

no visible @interface for 'ALAssets' declares the selector 'defaultRepresentation'

Comment: Can you edit your question cutting and pasting the precise error? (This doesn't seem like it could be the actual error.) Also, can you show us a little more context, showing us how `result` variable was set? (I'm assuming it was `enumerateAssetsUsingBlock`, but want to make sure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks - Andrew Romanov.

finally i got solution - this error is just because of i deleted "AssetsLibrary Framework" and reattached it.

so solution is :-
I reinstalled Xcode-6 and after installation i run my project it works good.

Answer (score 0):

AssetsLibrary, contain a class ALAsset. There is no ALAssets class in AssetsLibrary. May be you've created your custom class ALAssets (for example,  for list of the assets), if it is so, it is bad idea. You shouldn't create classes with the library prefix 'AL'. You can create your custom prefix and use it for your classes (For example: MMMAssets).

[image: code for implementation]

[image: Assets library contains defaultRepresentation class]

Comment: thanks for reply, i haven't created ALAssets custom class , i am using this class from AssetsLibrary.

Comment: Can you show me where defined ALAssets class? (In xCode "Jump to Definition")

Comment: thanks fro reply, i am new in Objective C programming , i tried (In xCode "Jump to Definition") on 'defaultRepresentation' - gets error:- symbol not found . for that i check (AssetsLibrary.framework -Headers- ALAsset.h )file that exist  - (ALAssetRepresentation *)defaultRepresentation;

Comment: In the error, you've shown, is displayed class __ALAssets__, I can't find this class in the library.  Can you show me where it is defined?

Comment: Can you add more code? (where do you create/get result instance?)

Comment: Did you import AssetsLibrary? May be you've imported ALAssetsLibrary? To import AssetsLibrary you can use: 
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h> or
@import AssetsLibrary;

It is very interesting problem.

Comment: Can you create example project for Git? (I can't reproduce your problem in my project.)